# Sample ASP.NET web application for IIS testing

Tags: iis, hosting, asp.net, share

I'm configuring a shared hosting environment for ASP.NET on IIS. I'm looking for a simple, freeware (possibly not dependent on a database) ASP.NET web application for testing purposes. Could you recommend something?

Answer (score 2):

if your just looking for any old .net application to test your server, there are many avialible, heres just a few of the top of my head:

- [DotNetNuke](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/)
- [Umbraco](http://umbraco.org/)
- [Mayando](http://mayando.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 1):

You can find many simple and free ASP.net applications on codeplex for your test. Here is an example:

[club starter kit](http://clubstarterkit.codeplex.com/)